# How to check last element's property of an array using MongoDB C# driver

Tags: c#, arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I have model classes defined below. I am using MongoDB 6.0.

```cs
public class App
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }    

    public List<Version> Versions { get; set; } = new List<Version>();

    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}

public class Version
{
    public DateTime DeployedDate { get; set; }

    public string DeploymentId { get; set; }

    public string Group { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to add another condition to the following C# query.

- The `Group` property of the last element of the `Versions` array should not be equal to "12345".

```cs
var applicationFilter = Builders<App>.Filter.Eq(a => a.IsDeleted, false) &    
    Builders<App>.Filter.Exists(a => a.Versions, true) &    
    Builders<App>.Filter.SizeGt(a => a.Versions, 0);
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1: Work with the [`$last`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last-array-element/) operator**

Doubt that currently there is no `$last` operator in MongoDB .NET syntax. But you can query with `BsonDocument`. MongoDB .NET driver provides the [implicit conversion from the `BsonDocument` to `FilterDefinition<TDocument>`](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.0/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_FilterDefinition_1_op_Implicit.htm).

```cs
applicationFilter &= new BsonDocument("$expr",
    new BsonDocument("$ne",
        new BsonArray
        {
            new BsonDocument("$last", "$versions.group"),
            "12345"
        }));
```

**Solution 2: Work with [LINQ3](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.14/reference/driver/crud/linq3/) provider**

If you use MongoDB.Driver with version 2.14 and above, you can utilize the query with the LINQ expression/way.

**Pre-requisites**: Enable LINQ3 provider in `MongoClientSettings`.

```cs
MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.FromConnectionString(
    /* Connection string */
);
settings.LinqProvider = MongoDB.Driver.Linq.LinqProvider.V3;

MongoClient _client = new MongoClient(settings);
```

```cs
applicationFilter &= Builders<App>.Filter.Where(x => x.Versions.Last().Group != "12345");
```